# codeigniter cant call function $config

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to call the pagination function so I do not get tired of rewriting the pagination code I've created. on this issue when I call the function, its function is not running with what I want.
pagination function does not display .

this is my code :

function pagination :

```
public function pagination(){

$config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['prev_link'] = '<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i>Previous Page';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['next_link'] = 'Next Page<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

}
```

this is my code that i want to showing pagination function :

```
public function dataRule(){
    if (!empty($this->session->userdata('username'))) {

        $row=$this->TabelRule_model->barisRule();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/diagnosaKucing/tabelrule';
        $config['total_rows'] = $row;
        $config['per_page'] = 8;
        $this->pagination();
        $start=$this->uri->segment(2);
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['rows'] =$row;
        $data['tabelrule'] = $this->TabelRule_model->tampilTabelRule($config['per_page'],$start);
        $this->load->view('pages/static/header');
        $this->load->view('pages/forms/tabelrule',$data);
        $this->load->view('pages/static/footer');
    }else {
        redirect('Login/signin');
    }

}
```

i dont want my code like this :

```
public function dataRule(){
    if (!empty($this->session->userdata('username'))) {

        $row=$this->TabelRule_model->barisRule();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/diagnosaKucing/tabelrule';
        $config['total_rows'] = $row;
        $config['per_page'] = 8;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i>Previous Page';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next Page<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $start=$this->uri->segment(2);
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['rows'] =$row;
        $data['tabelrule'] = $this->TabelRule_model->tampilTabelRule($config['per_page'],$start);
        $this->load->view('pages/static/header');
        $this->load->view('pages/forms/tabelrule',$data);
        $this->load->view('pages/static/footer');
    }else {
        redirect('Login/signin');
    }

}
```

the results I get : [pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiVtZ.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to style pagination links without config - codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096942/how-to-style-pagination-links-without-config-codeigniter)

Comment: I use that way too but when adding a new controller then I have to add pagination function in each of my functions and it takes up a lot of space. so what i want is to make 1 piece of function inside there is already pagination function and when i make the new controller unnecessary rewrite the function

Comment: it may be due to `$start=$this->uri->segment(2);` as 1st is controller , 2nd is function , 3rd is offset so use `$start=$this->uri->segment(3);`.hope it helps

Comment: still did not work

Comment: ok try this idea actually you defining `$config` in different function try to define it in same function where you are initializing pagination i mean to say all the `$config` values to be in same function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function isn't returning anything and it has a `$config` variable with local scope.

You should do it like this:

```
public function pagination(){

    $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    ...
    return $config;
}
```

And then:

```
public function dataRule(){
    if (!empty($this->session->userdata('username'))) {

    $row=$this->TabelRule_model->barisRule();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $config = $this->pagination();
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/diagnosaKucing/tabelrule';
    $config['total_rows'] = $row;
    $config['per_page'] = 8;

    $start=$this->uri->segment(2);
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    ...
```

And so on.

Comment: hey man can i ask something? why i cant use $this blablabla in function pagination or function in function

Comment: @FarisDewantoro Do you mean like setting a default value for pagination's configurations let's say: `$this->config` and use it else where in your controller?

Comment: i mean like this function cari(){
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT KodePertanyaan from tabelrule ");
$query = $query->result_array();
return $query;
}
public function (){
$data['cari']=$this->cari();
$this->load->view('pages/static/header');
$this->load->view('pages/action/updatePertanyaan',$data);
$this->load->view('pages/static/footer');
}            <- this not work why?

Comment: @FarisDewantoro Could you please update your question to see what you mean in a clean more detailed manner?